# lambda collecting within a ifPresent

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

How can I use the `collect` method to collect within a nested `ifPresent` method?

So far this is what I have:

```
List result = list.stream()
                  .findFirst()
                  .ifPresent(info -> {
                      info.getMap()
                          .stream()
                          .filter( entry -> entry.getKey().equals("test"))
                          .map(entry::getValue)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())                          
                   });
```

Comment: Why does it have to be an `ifPresent`?  Why not a `flatMap`?

Comment: Or rather a map(), in this case. Also, don't use raw types.

Comment: Why filter a Map on its key - that means you are iterating over all elements, and a Map exists to avoid that. So why not just use `info.getMap().get("test")` ? Something like `Optional<Object> result = list.stream().findFirst().flatMap(info -> Optional.ofNullable(info.getMap().get("test")));` -- why do you need a List in the first place as the result type?

Comment: I added a second edit to my answer with a couple of examples of what OP might be attempting to do (based on the above comments).  I think we have a comprehensive set of ways to answer any type of implementation s/he's trying to do at this point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might wanted to do this:

```
List result = list.stream()
    .limit(1)
    .flatMap(info -> // <-- removed brace {
        info.getMap().stream()
            .filter( entry -> entry.getKey().equals("test"))
            .map(entry::getValue)
    ) // <-- removed brace here too
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Let me explain:

`.limit(1)`: limits the stream only to the first element (or returns an empty stream if initial stream is empty)

`.flatMap()`: maps the stream into a new stream. in this case a new stream consisting of values from `Entry#getValue()` is returned

`.collect(Collectors.toList())`: at last the stream of values is collected into a list.

As Olivier Grégoire said in the comments, the following does work too:

```
List result = list.stream()
    .limit(1)
    .flatMap(info -> info.getMap().stream())
    .filter( entry -> entry.getKey().equals("test"))
    .map(entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which in my opinion is more readable and clearer indicates what the intents were.

Comment: I think you are supposed to invoke info.getMap().entrySet().stream(), instead of info.getMap().stream(), to get a Stream<Map.Entry> value, right?

Comment: flatMap accepts a stream returning function. Your inner lambda doesn't do that. You should `.flatmap(info -> info.getMap().stream()).filter(...).map(...).collect(...)`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire i think your version just has different semantics, but all in all they're identical. I updated the answer to show your way too :)

Comment: You're right. It's early morning for me and I didn't have my cup of coffee yet.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `info.getMap` returns a `java.util.Map`, I don't see why you need the inner stream pipeline at all.

Just use `get("test")` to obtain the value of the `"test"` key:

```
List result = 
    list.stream()
        .map(info -> info.getMap().get("test"))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .limit(1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

P.S., don't use a raw type. You should change the type of the returned list to `List<ValueType>` where `ValueType` is the type of values in the `info.getMap()` `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a `List<Info>` containing zero or more `Info`s, where `Info` is some object which has a `getMap()` method returning a `Map<String, Something>` and you want to end up with a `List<Something>`, which is all the values of the first list item's map which have the key test.

You want to `map` the optional instead of using `ifPresent`.  `ifPresent` is a terminal operation which doesn't return anything (just executes code).

```
list // List<Info>
    .stream() // Stream<Info>
    .findFirst() // Optional<Info>
    .map(info -> info.getMap().entrySet() // Set<Entry<String, Something>>
         .stream() // Stream<Entry<String, Something>>
         .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("test"))
         .map(Entry::getValue) // Stream<Something>
         .collect(toList()) // List<Something>
    ) // Optional<List<Something>>
    .orElse(Collections::emptyList) // List<Something>
```

If last line not specified then you'll be getting an `Optional<List<Info>>` back.

EDIT: Lino's answer with `limit` is more idiomatic, pick that one unless you really want to use `Optional` in this way.

### Edit 2:

Assuming your code above is your complete business logic, you probably just to find the value of "test" in the first item in your list (thanks Lino for `limit`).  That'd be:

```
list.stream() // Stream<List<Info>>
    .limit(1) // Stream<List<Info>> count 0/1
    .flatMap(info::getMap) Stream<Map<String, Something>> 0/1
    .map(map -> map.get("test")) Stream<Something> 0/1, possibly null
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) Stream<Something> 0/1
    .findFirst() Optional<Something>
```

For completeness, if you wanted to find ANY values of "test" in maps in your list, it'd be:

```
list.stream() // Stream<List<Info>>
    .flatMap(info::getMap) Stream<Map<String, Something>> 
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()) // Stream<Entry<String, Something>>
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("test"))
    .map(Entry::getValue) // Stream<Something>
    .collect(toList()) // List<Something>
```

Comment: Is `entry` in the `.map(entry::getValue)` a class? or a variable?

Comment: That's actually a typo I copied from OP's code.  It should be `Entry::getValue` (invoking the `getValue` method on `Entry`, which iirc is the container type when you call `entrySet()`).  It would only be `entry` if you used `entry -> entry.getValue()` like in the `filter` above.  Fixing my answer (but again, Lino's is more idiomatic).

Comment: I think your answer is better than mine, didn't know that `Optional#map()` even exists :)

Comment: The comments on OP's question are digging into why he's doing it this way anyway heh, but I think we both just tried to answer for the sake of how to correctly use streams for this :).  I prefer yours because it removes the unnecessary conversion between `List` and `Optional` (more succinct for sure).